# Youtube won't work on chromium

Tags: flash, youtube, chromium

I have Ubuntu 14.04LTS, and when I try playing a youtube video i "Ow, snap" message. I have already installed Pepper flash player, so I don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: And that's a programming question how exactly? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo this is programming question because i can't watch programming tutorials on youtube. :D